# How to check Azure Pricing tier change history for SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I created an AZURE SQL Database with S0 pricing tier, two months back. But somehow the pricing tier of the same database suddenly got upgraded to P15 for 10 days and then again downgraded to S0.

I want to check when and how this happened! Is there any way I can check pricing tier change history from Azure portal or using any Sql query?

Activity logs of Azure portal do not show any such pricing tier changes.

Comment: Hi,did you see my answer? If my answer can be helps, could please accept or vote it? Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Hi, none of these helped in my case. Mine is a CSP subscription and these option does not work for CSP Azure subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the portal you can scale the database:

[image]

There is [no automatic auto-scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-scale-resources), so somebody must have done manual changes.

//edit: Changing the SKU results in a "Update SQL Database" event in the activity log:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see a log of pricing tier changes by querying the [sys.dm_operation_status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-operation-status-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) dynamic management view.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_operation_status   
   WHERE major_resource_id = 'myddb'   
   ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

If you identify a pattern when these changes occur, for instance, the scale up or down occurs at the same time every day, [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#viewing-job-status-from-the-azure-portal) is a good place to verify if a job schedule have been created that changes the service tier.